Catch "request body too large" error in python on azure functions
Azure storage queue has a message size limit of 64KB. I want to catch this error when it occurs in azure functions. For that I use the following code:
@app.blob_trigger(arg_name='inputFile', path="blob",
                  connection='queue_con_str')
@app.queue_output(arg_name='outputInfo', queue_name='q-input',
                  connection='queue_con_str')
def process_input(inputFile: func.InputStream, outputInfo: func.Out[typing.List[str]]):
    data = json.loads(inputFile.read())
    o_data = [json.dumps(v) for v in data]

    try:
        outputInfo.set(o_data)
    except Exception as e:
        print("EXCEPTION ", e)
        print(type(e))

When the message is large, I get an exception but python cannot catch the error. I want to split the message if the error occurs. Instead I get a
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.process_input.  error from .NET. How to catch the exception in python?
Logged messages
Executed 'Functions.process_input' (Failed, Id=ae07d776-ecec-4544-96bb-2b598ef4033d, Duration=24506ms)
 System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.process_input. Azure.Storage.Queues: The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
 RequestId:d326abfd-d003-0071-116b-8483bb000000
 Time:2024-04-01T19:33:02.1219320Z
 Status: 413 (The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.)
 ErrorCode: RequestBodyTooLarge
 
 Additional Information:
 MaxLimit: 65536
 
 Content:
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>RequestBodyTooLarge</Code><Message>The request body is too large and exceeds the maximum permissible limit.
 RequestId:d326abfd-d003-0071-116b-84845b000000
 Time:2024-04-01T19:33:02.1219320Z</Message><MaxLimit>65536</MaxLimit></Error>
 
 Headers:
 Server: Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
 x-ms-request-id: d326abfd-d003-0071-116b-84845b000000
 x-ms-version: 2018-11-09
 x-ms-error-code: RequestBodyTooLarge
 Date: Mon, 01 Apr 2024 19:33:01 GMT
 Content-Length: 286
 Content-Type: application/xml


May we see the full traceback? Also, can you print after the except, and catch BaseException instead of Exception? Do you see that print?

It seems there's no direct way to catch such an error because the error occurs outside the execution context of the python function. Can you somehow handle this situation by implementing a check before the function app tries to process the blob?

@user70 that's kind of what I am doing now. Same number of messages can have different sizes, and I don't want to check if it's not necessary.

@Shishir Pandey If possible can you share your GitHub repo here?
